WebRTC `Allocation Quota Reached` is very frequent in Safari
To describe my use case simply, I'm building an application which will see peer connections using the TURN server quite frequently (relay candidates), and in many consecutive sessions. A lot of teardowns, and new connection establishment.
With Safari, my application runs into Allocation Quota Reached after 1-2 consecutive attempts of using the webpage and thus doesn't receive relay candidates. It's almost definitely a Safari thing, because with Chrome I was able to run my app for 15 consecutive session (with only 5-10s in between each). Also, when the error appears on Safari, it starts appearing on Chrome (where it didn't before I attempted on Safari)
My impression from tests is that with Safari, the allocations on the TURN server aren't being given  up instantly (or until an idle few mins timeout). So, it seems like the ICE candidates aren't being deallocated at the server upon connection teardown.
Does anyone know if there's a way around this issue with Safari? It's gotten me quite stuck these days, and for many un-disclosable reasons, Safari support is necessary.
I've tried pc.close to teardown the connection. I don't see any other way of more robustly closing down the connection (assuming that's the cause of the Safari error).
